# Filtering pornographic and forbidden content with PHP?

Tags: php, filtering

I've have build a simple social network, where users are able to register/login and post four types of data:

Text, Pictures, Videos and Files.

Everything is stored in the database with the TEXT-datatype. When they upload a pic/vid/file, the text is just the path to the related data on my server.

Now what I am really interested in, is how to filter adult/forbidden content like videos or pictures that are showing pornographic or violent data. Also it could be possible to upload movies separated in smaller files, as my upload limit is 100 MB for each file.

I guess YouTube filters movies with a comparison to an existing database. So they just have to compare chunks of data with the original file et voila, they filtered it. Therefore one can easily mirror the movie, and it will take much longer for YouTube to keep that file.

However, how is the pornographic/religious/violent data filtered?

I also have no idea for what keyword I have to search for. That also could help me.

Comment: Mostly the "Report Video" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a report button and if something is reported and is indeed considered "dirty", delete it and keep its hash in a database table, and then when a file gets uploaded check its hash against that table, so that they can't just reupload the same "dirty" content.

To not be in legal trouble if your users stumble upon dirty content, make sure you clearly point out in your terms of service that your site hosts user-generated content and you can't guarantee that all content is safe, so by using the website users agree to these terms. Get in touch with your lawyers as the laws in each country may vary.

Comment: Oh okay. How about being liable to prosecution, if there is violent content on my site? May I add a term like 'the user is liable for his own content' ?

Comment: Alright thank you. Tomorrow I will make a meeting with my lawyer and ask him what term to use and which paragraphs I need to refer to, to stay clean. :)